# not so obvious pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a class :

```
class X{
 public :
 void f ( int ) ;
 int a ;
} ;
```

And the task is "Inside the code provide declarations for :

- pointer to int variable of class X
- pointer to function void(int) defined inside class X
- pointer to double variable of class X"

Ok so pointer to int a will be just int *x = &a, right ? If there is no double in X can I already create pointer to double inside this class ? And the biggest problem is the second task. How one declares pointer to function ?

Comment: Are you being asked for regular pointers or pointers-to-members?

Comment: I think the questions are asking for pointer-to-member and pointer-to-member-function, although I could be wrong. Look up those, but first look up function pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called [***pointers to members***](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html). They are not regular pointers, i.e. not addresses, but "sort-of" offsets into an instance of the class (it gets a bit tricky with virtual functions.) So:

1. `int X::*ptr_to_int_member;`

   `void (X::*ptr_to_member_func)( int );`

   `double X::*ptr_to_double_member;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare them as pointer-to-members. Pointers to members are different than usual pointers in that they are the address of a member of a structure or class, not an absolute address like regular pointers.

For more information, read [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/cplr034.htm).

Answer (score 0):

A pointer to any type is declared with an '*' after the type name and the variable name:

```
Franks_Class * p_franks_class; // Declares a pointer to an instance of Franks_Class.
```

The more obscure declaration is for the function:

```
typedef void (*My_Int_Function_Ptr)(int parameter);
```

which declares a type (synonym), named My_Int_Function_Ptr, a pointer to a function taking an *int parameter* and returning `void`.

From this and a **good** C++ book, you should be able to answer the rest of your questions.